# create or update querystring without plugin

Tags: jquery

I want to update href of a menu item on click of a button, here is my code

```
function refreshReportMenu(){
    var ts = '&ts=' + new Date().getTime().string(16);
    $('ul.nav a.reps').each(function(){
       var href = $(this).attr('href');
        $(this).attr('href', href + ts);
    });
}
```

but the problem here is that it always append ts to href, I want to update ts value if its already in the href.

Comment: Are you trying to update the querystring in the browser, or just replace any querystring in the href attribute for the link ??

Comment: in href attribute only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well.. you could perhaps try

```
var reg = /(^|&)ts=(.*?)(&|$)/, ts = 'ts=' + new Date().getTime().toString(16);
$('ul.nav a.reps').each(function(){
   var href = $(this).attr('href');
   if ( href.match(reg) ) {
       href = href.replace(reg,"$1+"+ts+"$3");
   } else {
       href += "&" + ts;
   }
   $(this).attr('href', href);
});
```

It should work :)

Comment: few issues in above code, other than its perfect, update code with .getTime().toString(16) and href.match(reg)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('ul.nav a.reps').each(function(){
       var href = $(this).attr('href');
        $(this).attr('href', href + ts);
    });
```

think you went wrong here `$this` instead of `$(this)`

Comment: thx for the fix, but I am looking for a solution to update querystring

Answer (score 0):

try `.indexOf`

```
alert('Index: ' + $(this).attr('href').indexOf('ts'));
```

check

```
if($(this).attr('href').indexOf('ts') > 0)
{
    $(this).attr('href', href + ts);
}
```